# CollectionView issue mixing grouping with GridItemsLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, collectionview, itemtemplate

I'm trying to implement a Xamarin Forms CollectionView using Grouping and GridItemsLayout vertical mode and Span="2". I make the grouping work without problems, but when I add the GridItemsLayout with the Span set to 2 columns, it does not behave as it should. Still showing the collection as 1 column.

```
                <CollectionView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    IsVisible="{Binding VisibleCollection}"
                    IsGrouped="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">
                    <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label
                                FontSize="16"
                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            Span="2"
                            VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label BackgroundColor="Red" Text="TEST" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Label "TEST" still showing in 1 single column, and I want it to be shown as 2 columns:

**TEST  TEST**

instead of:

**TEST**

**TEST**

Anyone knows how I can make it possible with GridItemsLayout? btw, this issue is happenning on UWP

Comment: Yes, my problem comes from this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes when the collection view is initially "hide" and switching visibility.

Xamarin forms issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9079

Comment: I have this problem without any changes in visibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Label "TEST" still showing in 1 single column, and I want it to be shown as 2 columns

Thanks for taking time to report this problem, for my testing the problem occurs in Xamarin Forms earlier version, and it is fixed in current stable version. Please update your Xamarin.Forms Nuget Package version to  [**4.5.0.530**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/) . And please note `CollectionView` is available on iOS and Android, but is only **partially available** on the Universal Windows Platform. For more info please refer this [document](https://gist.github.com/hartez/7d0edd4182dbc7de65cebc6c67f72e14).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **GridItemsLayout** from main thread.

**Example**

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    BannerList.ItemsLayout = new GridItemsLayout(2,ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical);
    BannerList.ItemsSource = ImageList;
});
```

**This is worked for me.**

Comment: ...but not for me :(